# Copy Constructor in Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, adt, copy-constructor

Im a first year student and while going through my Linked List note's I saw a copy constructor been used. Previously when I study ADT Array based Implementation, I havent see a copy constructor. Why the copy constructor is been used in the Linked List? Is that important to implement a copy constructor?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Regardless of whether you copy an instance of Linked List or if you copy an element of it: Whenever you write a class that manages ressources on itself, consider the Rule Of Three (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/2630032)

Comment: I just going through the copy constructor implementation. It looks similar like adding Node. I just dont understand why they an a Deep Constructor in the Linked List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing the code it's impossible to say for sure, but I will say that for a linked-list implementation it is *highly likely* that a copy constructor and assignment operator are required, in order to [prevent your class from having broken copy semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) with respect to dynamic allocations performed by your constructor, and de-allocations performed by your destructor.

If you saw an implementation in the past that didn't have these, it is *highly likely* that it was broken/buggy/wrong, and this is not at all unusual out there on the internet where endless terrible beginner implementations exist and are passed off as "how you should do it" in non-peer-reviewed tutorials. It's even fairly common in University teaching material, sadly.

Learn C++ from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and read about the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/560648).
Then delete your implementation and use `std::list`!